# Should I use OAuth for a small business website?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I know it allows a third party to have access to the user's data of the another website. If I just want to make an e-commerce website with Facebook login, and it'll only be used by my customer, is it an overkill to use OAuth?

Answer (score 0):

For an ecommerce website you will require stuff such as phone number, address, pincode etc.. Facebook wont give you all of these things.
As not a lot of people save such info on fb,

Its wont be an overkill, infact it is much easier, but you wont benefit from it at all.

Thr best thing would be to get an write a custom login system, make it short and simple.Maybe even get a bulk sms module/service to verify phone numbers or order confirmations.

Answer (score 0):

If the Facebook login is the only way to login, it can be quite limiting for people having no Facebook account or not wanting to use it. But it's not difficult to implement and it can make your application safer (not keeping passwords in your database) and easier to use for Facebook users, which I think makes it worth the effort.

After the first successful Facebook authentication, you can ask users for all additional data you need not available from Facebook.

And if you support one OAuth2 provider, it's easy to add other ones later (such as Google).

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear. It'll be a custom login system besides Facebook. Do I need to include OAuth in order to use Facebook login?

Answer (score 0):

I would host the Website on [Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/) or one of the other big players (Azure, AWS) and use their Authentication systems and APIs.

In today's Cyber Security environment it seems almost "foolish" to use any other route. Why do you want to setup a "custom login system" when using things like [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) (Azure or AWS has things too) makes it so you can do 5 or 6 of the major Social Logins and/or a username password system while "someone else" deals with all the hassles of password management and prevention password breaches.

There is no way a "small business" can compete with the security and infrastructure that these "Big Player" provide.

Comment: Thanks, mate. That's a very good hint for me! I'll check them out.